# Spring Social & JPA - Having two datasources pointing to the same database

Tags: java, jpa, spring-social

I am currently working on a Java application that uses Spring Social to communicate with Twitter.  The application uses Spring Data (JPA) to manage users locally.

When I authorize access on Twitter and Twitter makes a request to the OAuth1 callback URL, my application chokes and I see the following in my log file (I've shortened the stacktrace):

```
ERROR 2013-08-18 16:05:09,511 http-bio-8080-exec-44]  org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor  [TransactionAspectSupport.completeTransactionAfterThrowing
(): "Application exception overridden by rollback exception"]
org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException: PreparedStatementCallback; uncategorized SQLException for SQL [insert into UserConnection (userId, providerId, providerUserId, ra
nk, displayName, profileUrl, imageUrl, accessToken, secret, refreshToken, expireTime) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)]; SQL state [null]; error code [0]; You can't operate 
on a closed Connection!!!; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: You can't operate on a closed Connection!!!
        at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:83)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:80)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:80)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:603)
...
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: You can't operate on a closed Connection!!!
        at com.mchange.v2.sql.SqlUtils.toSQLException(SqlUtils.java:118)
        at com.mchange.v2.sql.SqlUtils.toSQLException(SqlUtils.java:77)
        at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyConnection.prepareStatement(NewProxyConnection.java:171)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$SimplePreparedStatementCreator.createPreparedStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:1438)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:581)
        ... 94 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyConnection.prepareStatement(NewProxyConnection.java:135)
        ... 96 more
[WARN 2013-08-18 16:05:09,513 http-bio-8080-exec-44]  org.springframework.social.connect.web.ConnectController  [ConnectController.oauth1Callback(): "Exception while handling OAuth1 callback (Could not roll back JPA transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: unexpected error when rollbacking). Redirecting to twitter connection status page."]
```

After some research I believe I am essentially seeing the issue described here:
https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SOCIAL-384

For some reason the fact that Spring Social core uses a JdbcUsersConnectionRepository does not play nice with my JPA set up.  I understand that a plugin is available; however I decided to experiment with the datasource configurations and created two essentially identical datasource bean configurations (with different names) and tied one to Spring Social and the other to my entity manager configuration.

With this setup the above error goes away and I am able to see my Twitter user connection get persisted to the database.  My question is: is doing something like this a valid solution? What are some other scenarios that would require duplicate datasources?  On the flip side - what are possible repercussions for using such a configuration?

Answer (score 0):

Downside of this solution is that you need to reduce maximum capacity of connection pool.

Example: imagine that you have a connection pool with max 30 connections in it. Now you want to add another datasource for Spring Social. I suppose that each your user will use 2 datasources simultaneously. So you need 2 connection pools with max 15 connections in each. Now it will be much easier to hit the limit.